# How to accurately clip a figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Often I want to save a matplotlib figure without any additional white space around the edge. I can use zero padding specification in tight layout or constrained layout, but they clip the figure without taking into consideration the width of lines or spines near the boundary. As is shown in the flowing image, matplotlib often clips the figure along solid line instead of outer dashed line, truncating both ends of the blue curve line. I wonder if there's a straight way to fix this clipping problem without leaving any additional paddings around the figure.

[image: accurate clipping]

Below is an tiny example to present the current problem, where both the bottom and right spines are truncated to one half of desired width:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2), constrained_layout=True)
fig.set_constrained_layout_pads(wspace=0, hspace=0, w_pad=0, h_pad=0)
ax.set_title('Clipped spines')
ax.set_ylabel('Bottom and right')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.tick_params(length=0)
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_color('red')
    spine.set_linewidth(5)
fig.savefig('clipped_fig.png', dpi=300)
```

[image: Truncated clipping]

Comment: Please provide code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Did you try bbox_inches='tight' in savefig?

Comment: @JodyKlymak Yes, but this does not solve current problem.

Comment: @Abbas Thanks for remindering. See edited problem above

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing but probably that is not trivial to solve as stated.

What is easy to do is just output including enough white space to avoid clipping and then automatically trim the image later (for example with ImageMagick `-trim` option, or coding it explicitly with PIL in case ImageMagick is not available).

Comment: Thanks. But I am mostly working with vector graphics and this approach might not work very well.

Comment: @gthink: I saw the png and thought that was the final output you were looking for. Unfortunately it is a common problem for a lot of vector software to ignore line thickness when computing bounding boxes.